Replace form response email address with name from master list
I have a sheet with a tab/column of email addresses submitted via Google Form (FORM RESPONSES/EMAIL). I have written a formula that counts the unique occurrences of EMAIL and outputs the COUNT.
I have another sheet with two columns: master list of EMAIL addresses and associated NAMES.
I would like to know what formula I might use to achieve a list on a third sheet of NAMES (associated with the email addresses counted earlier) and COUNT.
FORM RESPONSES:



B




email1


email2


email3


email1


email1


email2



MASTER EMAIL LIST



A
B




email1
Thomas


email2
BeckyJ


email3
PaulaG



CURRENT OUTPUT
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:B,"SELECT B, COUNT(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY B ORDER BY COUNT(B) DESC LIMIT 10 LABEL COUNT (B) ''",0)




B
count




email1
3


email2
2


email3
1



DESIRED OUTPUT



A
count




Tom
3


BeckyJ
2


PaulaG
1



I have tried multiple variations of formulae that seem to break everything. Is this possible?

Since you already have a working QUERY, you can replace the values with XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP and create a virtual column with names instead of mails:
=QUERY(INDEX(XLOOKUP('Form Responses 1'!B2:B,Master!A:A,Master!B:B,)),
"SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC LIMIT 10 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''",0)


Thank you so much. Works like a charm. I hadn’t considered XLOOKUP. I know enough to be relatively dangerous but it was beyond me. I will learn about XLOOKUP specifically. Again, I really appreciate it.
